# Transfer coins from Armory paper backup without Armory

Tags: armory, coldstorage

I have an armory offline installation on a USB stick with Ubuntu. From this wallet I have a paper backup. To access my funds I tried to install Armory on Mac OS and Windows 7 with no luck. The best result was on the mac. Bitcoin QT is running and is completely synchronized. But if I start Armory it stays at status "Organizing Blockchain" forever. I just ordered a Trezor to get around this problem in the future.

So my question: How can I transfer my coins from the armory cold-storage to a new address without an armory online installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is step-by-step

1. Run armory in offline mode (simply run `armory --offline`)
2. Import the wallet into armory if you haven't already. (Import wallet, etc) (you probably don't need to do this if you have it on USB, just run that instance)
3. Click on the wallet and click "Backup This Wallet" and enter the password.
4. Select "Export Key Lists" and click the button at the bottom
5. Check "Private Key (Plain Base58)" from the checklist and nothing else.
6. Select "Omit spaces in key data", as these may cause an "Invalid private key encoding" during import
7. Take each private key listed in the window and import them into some other program (this might take a while)
8. Transfer the funds from the private key to a new address.